# With Maple how can i prompt the user to answer a boolean expression?

Tags: maple

The exact question would be "is the equation you want to use x=f(Xo)". This is in an if statement already so if true then continue if not then prompt user to enter a different function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Boolean expression evaluation from user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506884/boolean-expression-evaluation-from-user)

Answer (score 1):

Your bit about its already being inside an `if statement` isn't very workable because that doesn't allow for an alternative value to be assigned to something in the case that the initial response is negative.

You should be able to work with something like this. Call `p()`, and assign its result to a `ans`, say, and then work with that value (and/or test it for some properties).

```
restart:

p := proc()
local answer, oldprompt, res1, res2;
  oldprompt := interface(':-prompt'=``);
  try
    printf("Is the equation you want to use x=f(Xo)?  (y/n)\n");
    res1 := readline(-1);
    if member(res1,{"y;","y","yes;","yes"}) then
      answer := x=f(Xo);
    elif member(res1,{"n;","n","no;","no"}) then
      printf("Enter your equation.\n");
      res2 := readline(-1);
      answer := parse(res2);
    else
      printf("Response not recognized\n");
    end if;
  catch:
  finally
    interface(':-prompt'=oldprompt);
  end try;
  if answer='answer' then NULL else answer end if;
end proc:

ans := p();
```

[edited below]

It is possible to get it a little closer to your original. With procedure `p` as below the returned result will be one of true/false/FAIL and could be used in a conditional. In the case that the return values if false (because of the response to the initial query) then a second query is made about the choice of another expression.

This version of `p` takes two arguments, the first is the suggested initial equation. The second is a name which can be assigned any alternative.

```
restart:

p := proc(candidate, resultvar)
local result, oldprompt, res1, res2;
  oldprompt := interface(':-prompt'=``);
  try
    printf(sprintf("Is the equation you want to use %a?  (y/n)\n",
                   candidate));
    res1 := readline(-1);
    if member(res1,{"y;","y","yes;","yes"}) then
      result := true;
      assign(resultvar,candidate);
    elif member(res1,{"n;","n","no;","no"}) then
      result := false;
      printf("Enter your equation.\n");
      res2 := readline(-1);
      assign(resultvar,parse(res2));
    else
      printf("Response not recognized\n");
      result := FAIL;
    end if;
  catch:
  finally
    interface(':-prompt'=oldprompt);
  end try;
  return result;
end proc:
```

Now we can test it out.

```
p(x=f(X0), 'ans');

ans;
```

We could also use the call to `p` inside an `if` statement. Eg,

```
if p(x=f(X0), 'ans') then
   "accepted";
else
   "new choice made";
end if;

ans;
```

Here, answering "n" to the first query will make the conditional test see a `false` value, but the named argument `ans` will get assigned to as a side-effect.