# Boolean expression evaluation from user

Tags: maple

How does one, in Maple, prompt the user to answer a true or false (or yes or no) question that can be evaluated by your program like how a boolean would be in java? The exact question would be "is the equation you want to use x=f(Xo)". This is in an if statement already so if true then continue with the program and if false then prompt the user to input the equation that they want to use.

Comment: this belongs on stackoverflow

Comment: I don't think this is related to Mathematics :/

Comment: possible duplicate of [With Maple how can i prompt the user to answer a boolean expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506372/with-maple-how-can-i-prompt-the-user-to-answer-a-boolean-expression)